# 79 character line width Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, formatting

I am doing lots of programming in Symfony 2, the PHP framework. When I program in Python, I don't have much trouble keeping my lines up to 79 characters long, but when I program in PHP, especially in Symfony with its long bundle names, I find it very difficult to maintain the 79 character line width and keep the code nice looking and easy to follow at the same time. For example, the code below is very difficult to wrap to 79 characters and keep it "nice".

```
return $this->render('MyDemoCodeVendorBundle:Default:preregister_service_vendor.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
```

Do you have any suggestions/style recommendation as to how to format the code for this rather short line width? Thank you!

Comment: What's the point in maintaining your line width 79 characters long these days?

Comment: It has advantages - keeps your code short to the point that you can have multiple terminals open on one screen side by side, forces you to come up with succinct variable names, enforces the law of demeter. There are many folks who follow that standard these days and they have strong arguments.

Comment: IMHO it has nothing to do with law of Demeter. Opening multiple terminals is no argument either (open one more and 79 characters is too much). Give your templates shorter name if you really care. Or choose shorter bundle names. You could also use @Template annotation which is a bit shorter. I don't really see an issue here. I guess you're more likely to choose shorter template paths in python ;)

Comment: It doesn't have anything directly to do with the law of demeter, but it does help being conscious of it because short lines discourage method chaining, which is usually a sign of breaking the law of demeter. Nonetheless, I didn't mean to post this question to start a discussion about whether or not 79 characters is reasonable these days. I wanted to hear from the folks who do follow that rule how they deal with it in web frameworks that tend to be unfriendly with such short lines.

Comment: You can break lines to make them shorter, chaining will still work. That's why short lines won't help with enforcing law of demeter. I think it's a misunderstanding to think of them in the same context. Law of demeter has nothing to do with long lines. It's about coupling. Btw, line length is not forced by Symfony itself.

Comment: I know the length is not enforced by Symfony itself. It just naturally results from Symfony bundle naming architecture. I could wrap long bundle names, but that's ugly and hard to read. I think ChrisC provided exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks for your input, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using a widely accepted standard like PSR-2: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md .  There are a few examples on that page that deal with long lines.  PSR-2 suggests a "soft" limit of 120 characters, rather than your preference for 79 characters, but by following their guidelines, I would write the line like this:

```
return $this->render(
    'MyDemoCodeVendorBundle:Default:preregister_service_vendor.html.twig',
    array('form' => $form->createView())
);
```

That gives you 75 characters max, assuming 4 space indentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! So they say it "should" be a soft limit. If there is a soft limit, the rule is not really that "enforced" I guess.  Your line is 75 characters, but that's because it's outside of a function. Add it inside a function, which by itself is indented because it's in a class, and you're way beyond 79 characters. Thanks though!

Comment: They make a point of the rule not being "enforced", but if you wish to do that on your own projects, you're able to of course.  When you're dealing with the long bundle names/namespaces Symfony projects can give you it's sometimes difficult to keep string lengths down without compromising readability.  e.g. If you really wanted to hit 79 characters, you could by renaming your twig file, but it might not be as clear what the twig file was for.  I generally find using PSR-2 with a 120 character limit is a decent enough compromise to keep things short and relatively descriptive at the same time.

Comment: Agreed. 120 characters is something I never needed to exceed. I guess I will try to keep most of my code under 80 characters and if it has to exceed, like the bundle names or similar situations that would severely diminish readability, I will follow the 120 rule.

Comment: I also found this excellent post about the merit of 80 character limit: http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/276